# Toggle power icon on click the push Button in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, uibutton, toggle, qt-designer

In PyQt5 I want a functionality in which push button having an icon of power:

on press shows one image of power ON:
[image]
on pressing again shows an image of power OFF: [image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # main dialog box
        self.setWindowTitle("Hatchary System")
        self.resize(1032, 665)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);")
        
        button = QPushButton('', self)
        button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 71, 61))
        button.setStyleSheet("border: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        button.setText("")
        button.setIcon(QIcon('/home/lenovo/Downloads/feather-White/power.svg'))
        button.setCheckable(True)
        button.toggle()
        button.setIcon(QIcon('/home/lenovo/Pictures/images/feather/power.svg'))
        button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.show()
        
        
        
app = QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Output: [image]

I am new to PyQt5. I know this code is not correct but unable to find a way to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

A push button emits the signal `clicked()` when it is activated by the mouse, the Spacebar or by a keyboard shortcut. 
Connect to this signal to perform the button's action.

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
```

---

> `checked` : bool
>
> This property holds whether the button is checked
>
> Only checkable buttons can be checked. By default, the button is unchecked.

```
self.button.isChecked()
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # main dialog box
        self.setWindowTitle("Hatchary System")
        self.resize(1032, 665)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);")

# +++   vvvv        
        self.button = QPushButton('', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 71, 61))
        self.button.setStyleSheet("border: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.button.setText("")
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon('off.png'))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)               # +++
        
    def button_clicked(self):                                          # +++
        if self.button.isChecked():                                    # +++
            self.button.setIcon(QIcon('on.png'))                       # +++
        else:                                                          # +++
            self.button.setIcon(QIcon('off.png'))                      # +++
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

**off.png**

[image]

**on.png**

[image]

Comment: Can we do the same in QT designer?